# Alternative for mongodb $push function in postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Converting the MongoDb queries into postgresql.

In mongoDb we the basic usage of $push is as follows :
 https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Is there any alternative for this in postgresql or we need to implement it using the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using *array_agg*  function in Postgres.

See Sample code(shamelessly copied ) : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/21b2b/1